# how to implement a component in ionic2 that can be invoked from service

Tags: angular, ionic2

i want to build a component that works the same way as some ionic official components like loading, alert, actionsheet...

which means i can show a component by calling some function from a service. but i can't figure out how to achieve that, can somebody point me a direction. thanks.

let's say here is a component named ABCComponent and a controller named ABCController, this component will be used everywhere in my app like loading.

```
@Component({
...
})
export class ABCComponent{

}
```

and in homepage, i want to show this component

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private abcController: ABCController) {
    abcController.create().present();

  }
}
```

Comment: Ionic is open source - you can go take a look at their code to see how they did it: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/src/components/action-sheet

Comment: thank you for your reply, i looked at the source code. find present() in [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/app/app.ts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/app/app.ts),
i think this code is what i am looking for.
`return portal.insertPages(-1, [enteringView], opts);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it will do the job: you can  put the content that you want to show in a page calls ABCComponent, and then show it using `PopoverController`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/

Your ABCComponent page can be styled so that it looks like a customized dialog box, or just a picture with transparent background on top of your main app.

Comment: thank you. it's a very efficient way to implement what i need.